# Akka.Hosting - Dependancy Injection in Actor parameter

Tags: akka.net

How to inject parameters to Actors using Akka.Hosting?
i.e. public ExampleActor(Service1 service){ _service = service; .... }

Service1 is a Service added to IServiceCollection during startup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Akka.DependencyInjection](https://getakka.net/articles/actors/dependency-injection.html) with Akka.Hosting via the following syntax:

```
// arrange
using var host = await StartHost(collection =>
{
    collection.AddAkka("MyActorSys", (builder, sp) =>
    {
        builder.WithActors((system, registry, resolver) =>
        {
            var singletonActor = system.ActorOf(resolver.Props<SingletonActor>(), "singleton");
            registry.TryRegister<SingletonActor>(singletonActor);
        });
    });
});

// act
var singletonInstance = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IMySingletonInterface>();
var singletonActor = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ActorRegistry>().Get<SingletonActor>();
var singletonFromActor =
    await singletonActor.Ask<IMySingletonInterface>(SingletonActor.GetSingleton.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

// assert
singletonFromActor.Should().Be(singletonInstance);
```

The `WithActors` line has an overload which exposes the `DependencyResolver` - that uses the `IServiceProvider` under the hood and you can use `DependencyResolver.Props<TActor>(non-DI'd arguments...)` to instantiate an actor that resolves dependencies through its constructor.

Comment: Yes, That's what I did. I suppose there was possible to construct actor using DI without passing the resolved service by design but at runtime

Comment: if you want to resolve the service at runtime, have your actor accept an `IServiceProvider` dependency in its constructor (that will get injected automatically) - or you can do the following `DependencyResolver.For(Context.ActorSystem)` - that will give you access to the SP without DI.